# Changing import package alias from angular2 to @angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

How can I change package alias to use in import?
I'll use ng2-bootstrap and it searches for @angular/core and I'm referencing it as angular2/core. It's crashing my screen!

Comment: can't you do like import { component } from "@angular/core" ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 2.0.0-rc.0, all dependencies have been in this new "@angular/" form rather than the "angular2/" one. If you want to revert back, you simply have to change your dependencies in your `package.json` file to the version of Angular 2 you want.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2: "2.0.0-beta.17"
}
```

Angular 2.0.0-beta.17 is the latest version that uses the older angular dependency.

Comment: I'm using beta 15. Which is the newest version? Because I tried beta 17 and the problem persists.

Comment: That's strange, the newest version right now is 2.0.0-rc4 which has been out for about a month now. The beta versions should work the way you want. Could you maybe show your `package.json`?